# ¿Cómo se Puede Rotar Varias Veces una Imagen con los Valores de esta Función?

Tags: vb.net

Mi pregunta es la del titulo, tengo el siguiente método que las Rota pero cuando lo repito mas veces ya no se hace, ¿Alguien sabe porque me pasa esto?

El Metodo

```html
Public Sub Rotar45(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim Ima As Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
        Dim GRAF As Graphics = Imagen.CreateGraphics
        GRAF.Clear(Color.White)
        GRAF.TranslateTransform(80.0F, 20.0F)
        GRAF.RotateTransform(45.0F)
        Dim L As Integer = ((Imagen.Width / 3) - (Imagen.Width / 3) - (Imagen.Width / 3)) ' / 3
        Dim T As Integer = ((Imagen.Height / 3) - (Imagen.Height / 3) - (Imagen.Height / 3)) ' / 3
        GRAF.DrawImage(Ima, L, T, Imagen.Width, Imagen.Height)
        GRAF.Save()

    End Sub
```

Comment: es que no modifica `Imagen` simplemente la usa como base para crear un graphics y dibujar la rotación

Comment: Entonces, ¿ Cómo se establece que la imagen vaya al PictureBox.Image Después de la Rotación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he podido solucionarlo gracias a alo Malbarez con su comentario, he guardado la imagen y cargado de nuevo en el picturebox con el siguiente código:

```html
Public Sub Rotar45Derecha(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim FreeFilePath As String = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Imagen.bmp"


        Dim Ima As Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
        Dim B As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim GRAF As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
        GRAF.Clear(Color.White)
        GRAF.TranslateTransform(100.0F, -25.0F)
        GRAF.RotateTransform(22.5F)
        Dim L As Integer = ((Imagen.Image.Width / 12) - (Imagen.Image.Width / 12) - (Imagen.Image.Width / 12)) ' / 3
        Dim T As Integer = ((Imagen.Image.Height / 12) - (Imagen.Image.Height / 12) - (Imagen.Image.Height / 12)) ' / 3
        GRAF.DrawImage(Ima, L, T, Imagen.Image.Width, Imagen.Image.Height)
        GRAF.Save()
        'Dim F As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image.Width, Imagen.Image.Height, GRAF)
        'MFS.FileDelete(FreeFilePath)
        B.Save(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.Load(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    End Sub
```